# Downloading Swampy on Windows

Tags: python

I am a Windows user learning Python who wants to get Swampy working.  I downloaded the .zip file, which went to my downloads folder.  Where do I go from there to get it so it works with my Python 2.7.1?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow these instructions: [Swampy: Installation Instructions](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/install.html).